# How to capture html form input with flask using jquery chosen multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask, jquery-chosen

I have an HTML form with `jquery-chosen` multiple selection of countries. I want to send this input to `Flask` through the POST request. The problem is that Flask does not capture the selections.

When I do not use js chosen, it works:

```
<div class = "webform">
            <form method="POST" action = "/monthly_active" name = "countries">
            <p>Select countries</p>
                <select multiple id="Country" name="Country">     
                <option>Select...</option>
                <option value="DE">DE</option>
                <option value="AT">AT</option>
                <option value="RU">RU</option>
                <option name="PL">PL</option>
                <option name="IT">IT</option>
                <option name="GB">GB</option>
                <option name="BR">BR</option>
                </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

But with js chosen it does not work:

```
    <form method="POST" action = "/monthly_active" name = "chart_options" >
    <p>Select countries</p>
    <select name = "countries[]" data-placeholder="Countries" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <option value="AT">AT</option>
        <option value="GB">GB</option>              
        <option value="RU">RU</option>
        <option selected>DE</option>
        <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
        <option selected>ES</option>
        <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>  

    <script> $(".chosen-select").chosen(); </script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

In Flask I use `request.form.getlist()` to get the input list. 
The thing is I very very basic with HTML and javascript, thus, I am stuck how to manage this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

My mistake was in `request.form.getlist('chart_options')`:
I passed the name of the form there whereas I had to pass the name of the `<select>`
This worked:

`target_countries = request.form.getlist('countries[]')`